# how to use the kloudless api_key

Tags: cloud, kloudless

I'm using a kloudless example to build a text editor that saves files to the cloud. In this line, I replaced the 'api_key' with my API key. It still gives a syntax error at this line. I'm new to using cloud APIs, so any help would be appreciated!

kloudless.configure(api_key=os.environ['KLOUDLESS_API_KEY'])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`api_key` is the keyword argument that kloudless.configure takes, so you would want to pass your api key as the value of that (so where `os.environ['KLOUDLESS_API_KEY']` is).

If you'd like to see an example of text editor that uses the Kloudless SDK, you can take a look at https://github.com/vinodc/cloud-text-editor.